# Export matlab objects into json files

Tags: json, matlab, object, export

I need to export MATLAB objects into json files. I can do structures (with `savejson`), but it doesn't seem to work with objects. It says

> Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Also, this is for a standalone application, and I don't expect the users to have Python (probably not even Java).

Any idea?

Comment: What does Python have to do with this? And have you actually tried `set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)`?

Comment: Try converting the object to structure first with `s = struct(obj)`. Also, what Matlab version are you using?

Comment: Is this error occurring for any object, or just for some particular example you have? If it's the latter, details about the object may help diagnosis of the problem. Also, adding the code that's causing the problem to the question would help.

Comment: Please post the code that is used to generate the object (or at least a minimal example which reproduces the problem)

Answer (score -1):

I think Python has nothing to do with it - I just found someone who did it with Python.

I didn't try any object, and I'm suspecting that the problem is my objects. s = struct(obj) works, but j = savejson(s) gives me again the error message. The objects are actually generated by a few hundred lines code, and it includes a somehow confidential input data; in a nut, it's a biological system - creatures which eat each other on islands. So I have one class of creatures, one of islands etc. and all are handles. Creatures point at islands and "creatures on islands" (another class) and on predators and preys which are again creatures, and they point at islands and islands point at creatures... I'm afraid it just tries to get to the end of this structure, and gets stuck in an infinite loop. Perhaps, something like "export it into structure but just first level" or something like that would help.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, it adds further explanations. Please delete this answer and add the required information to your question. If you suspect a simple loop in your object structure to cause the problem, try to [create a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Further, you are using 3rd party code, please link the `savejson` you are using. There are multiple functions with that name available public.